# Use Scrum for multiple linked projects

Tags: scrum

I managed the development of a kind of e-market place with some elements:

- App for buyers (anyone):

  - Android app
  - IOS app
- Website for buyers (anyone) to sell products
- Website platform  for sellers (shop only): CMS-CRM-ERP
- App for sellers (shop only):

  - Android app
  - IOS app for sellers
- Website platform for intern marketer team: CMS-CRM-ERP

How can I use Scrum for so many platforms which are connected? Do I have to separate each element as a different project? How to control the connection between them? Same stories or duplicate? And so on...

Comment: Just an aside; Scrum is not an acronym (SCRUM), it is a word named after the rugby practise of protecting the ball in order for a team member to gain possession and move it down the field.  It is simply Scrum.  Like Ford, Amazon or the word monday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you've reached to the point where Scrum falls short (at least in my opinion). Scrum is really tough to implement when you have many interconnected teams that depend on one another. Why? Because you care about the whole and not about what's being produced in each and every team sprint.

I would REALLY recommend looking at a Kanban portfolio implementation. You can take a look how we do this at Kanbanize by reading the [Kanban for Software Development](https://kanbanize.com/kanban-resources/case-studies/kanban-for-software-development-teams/) case study. It's a long read, but if you master it you will never ever look back to Scrum.

Another thing that I'd like to recommend is getting yourself acquainted with the [Kanban Portfolio](https://kanbanize.com/blog/project-portfolio-management-strategy-guide-for-cios/) concept. It allows you to have one master board, where all your projects are and then many connected Kanban boards, which link to the master one. This is a great way to keep the overall work in progress under control and deliver features / projects much faster.

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous ways of slicing this answer but fundamentally you need to ask the question of yourself; **is each of those platform elements a separate project or are they all linked to a common project which serves a common user or set of users and, crucially, how many developments teams do you have working on the things to be done?**

My limited assessment is that you are discussing a single backlog of work which should be divided into Themes, Epics and User Stories.

You can find a more detailed explanation here:  https://www.mountaingoatsoftware.com/blog/stories-epics-and-themes

**User Stories**

> A user story is simply something a user wants.

User stories can and often are part of a larger collection of functionality which we refer to as Epics

**Epics**

> A Scrum epic is a large user story.  Similar to how a single movie can be an Action movie or a Romance movie

**Themes**

> Finally, “theme” is a collection of user stories. We could put a rubber band around that group of stories I wrote about monthly reporting and we'd call that a “theme.”   For instance all James Bond movies are part of a theme.

**Projects or Teams**

Once you have a healthy and well understood backlog, with some detailed stories and a simple categorization system for Themes and Epics you will be in a great position to understand how many development teams you need and how they should be structured.

The beauty of having a backlog is that teams can dip in and out of the themes and epics based on business value and priority rather than having to deliver entire functional areas.

You can find more information here but understanding the basics of Scrum will go a long way to helping you answer your own question which is the nature of the Agile values and the iterative frameworks within which we work.

**Self Organisation**

A key principle of the Scrum framework is that of self-organizing team which has autonomy into it's own working structure.

https://www.infoq.com/news/2015/02/establishing-self-organized-team

So ask the team how they think they should be structured.